# Make DBT choose the schema in dbt_project.yml instead of the name of the source

Tags: python, dbt

Here is how I formatted my dbt_project.yml

```
name: 'project_name'
version: '0.1.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'project_name'

model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


sources:
  dbt_proj:
    business-unit-x:
      +database: "BUSINESS_UNIT_X_{{ env_var('SF_ENV')}}"
      gold:
        +schema: GOLD
      silver:
        +schema: SILVER
      bronze:
        +schema: BRONZE
```

Here is in example of a source, in the folder business-unit-x/silver:

```
version: 2    
sources:
  - name: I_DONT_WANT_TO_BE_USED_AS_SCHEMA
    tables:
      - name: table_name
        columns:
        - name: column_name
```

Is there an option to make DBT choose the schema in my dbt_project.yml instead of a schema or name property in my source ?

If not, how to configure the schema property to synchronize with the dbt_project.yml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Issue comment](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/3105#issuecomment-779761596)  there is no way of parsing jinja in the `dbt_project` file.

So your best option may be

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: <source_name>
    database: "BUSINESS_UNIT_X_{{ env_var('SF_ENV')}}"
    tables:
      - name: <table_name>
      - ...
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.